# How to change animation direction on pushViewController on leftBarButtonItem?

Tags: swift, navigation, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, swift4.2

I've added a leftBarButtonItem to a NavigationBar(in conjunction with NavigationController). The leftBarButtonItem is on the top ViewController.

When I use the pushViewController func to go the next ViewController, the animation is from right to left, the same as when pressing a button on the right side of the navigationBar.

How can I change the animation direction to go from left to right, same as for example in Tinder when pressing the left button on the navigation bar?

Here's the code:

```
let profileButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.showProfile))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = profileButton

@objc func showProfile() {
    let profileViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profile") as! ProfileViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To animate while push to another viewController, you can use **CATransition**

```
@objc func showProfile() {
    let profileViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profile") as! ProfileViewController
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    transition.type = CATransitionType.push
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft       
    navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
}
```

You can change the animation direction as **fromRight, fromTopfromBottom**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the direction of UINavigationController.
In order to achieve that, you'll have to create it on your own. 
If you want to implement a menu, you can check out [SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu).

Comment: Sidemenu tip appreciated! If I would be to create the transition manually, how would I go about in achieving the desired animation?

Comment: Let's assume you want to have a rootViewController, another one from the right, and another one from the left. 3 ViewControllers in total.
I would use a `UIScrollView` and add those three ViewControllers to it, adjust their frames so they will be places one after the other (y=0, x={screenWidth * positionIndex}, set the `paging` property of the scrollView to true, and finally set the content size to the amount of sizes of the viewControllers.

Comment: Maybe this tutorial will be a good start for you:
https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/create-a-horizontal-paging-uiscrollview-with-uipagecontrol-swift-4-xcode-9-a3dddc845e92

Comment: Found another git repo that may help.
https://github.com/fortmarek/SwipeViewController

Comment: A different approach will be with UIPageViewController https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller

Comment: Hmm, good tips, will actually look into those too! Although not exactly the behaviour I'm looking to implement, the center VC contains a GMSMapView, so I'll most likely need to dig deeper, make the transitions then manually and look up how to do the custom transition implementations. It's interesting that there's no "easy" way to choose the animation direction in navigationController, would probably be useful for also a lot of other people out there than myself.

Comment: You mentioned Tinder, I thought you wanted the draggable screen. Maybe start with implementing a button tap will push a new childViewController to the screen with animation from the left and from the right by an enum you send it. you can deal with the gestures later.

Comment: This is actually funny, I've never noticed that the middle screen of Tinder is draggable, I've always pressed on the top buttons to move :) I looked into UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, that looks like a solution, although feels a bit overkill for the desired effect

Comment: That's why I think you better start with a simple animation for a `childViewController`. although I believe, thinking a bit further, `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` is the right approach.